# sprintf error in MATLAB when trying to save cell array with strings and numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, printf

I am iterating through a directory and storing the full path of a file and its label in a cell matrix in Matlab this way:

```
 image_directory=dir(['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2)]);

            for j=3:size(image_directory,1)

                  myCellArray{index_image}{1}=['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2) '/' image_directory(j).name];
                  myCellArray{index_image}{2}=label;
                  index_image=index_image+1;
            end
       end
   end4
```

After I finish filling this cell matrix I want to save its contents (strings and integers) in a text file. I did something like the suggestion in (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112695-how-to-write-an-array-containing-letters-and-number-to-file). Here Is what I tried:

```
fid = fopen('data_out.txt','w');

for i=1:size(myCellArray,1)

    fprintf(fid, '%s \t %s\n', myCellArray{i,1}, sprintf('%d ', myCellArray{i,2}));
end

fclose(fid);
```

The problem is, when I execute this source code in matlab I have the following error:

```
Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in write_files (line 50)
            fprintf(fid, '%s \t %s\n', myCellArray{i,1}, sprintf('%d', myCellArray{i,2}));
```

What Is wrong with my code?

Comment: is `myCellArray{i,2}` a number?

Comment: Yes, it is an integer number representing the label of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If `myCellArray{i,2}` is just one integer, I think you can just use,

```
fprintf(fid, '%s \t %d\n', myCellArray{i,1}, myCellArray{i,2});
```

Comment: There is another error using the proposed solution: Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in write_files (line 51)
                fprintf(fid, '%s \t %d\n', myCellArray{i,1}, myCellArray{i,2})

Comment: well, then you must have a cell inside a cell, because this would work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I just changed

```
image_directory=dir(['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2)]);

        for j=3:size(image_directory,1)

              myCellArray{index_image}{1}=['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2) '/' image_directory(j).name];
              myCellArray{index_image}{2}=label;
              index_image=index_image+1;
        end
   end
end
```

with:

```
image_directory=dir(['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2)]);

        for j=3:size(image_directory,1)

              myCellArray{index_image,1}=['path_for_directory/' char(folder1) '/' char(folder2) '/' image_directory(j).name];
              myCellArray{index_image,2}=label;
              index_image=index_image+1;
        end
   end
```

end

In other words, There were typos in the code that fills the cell matrix.